# Adapt width div with transform rotate and change text

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I have a problem with a specific style. I have a string "Historic" in a div with CSS transform rotate, positioned on a specific part of sibling div. If I change the string by "Historique" (for i18n), the div move.

I wish the div keep at the same place when string has changed. Thank you for answers.

```css
#main {
 margin: 50px;
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 background: #eee;
 border: thin solid #bbb;
}

#tag {
 position: absolute;
    left: -36px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 9px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    background: red;
    color: white;
    bottom: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    max-height: 20px;
}

.content {
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
 <div id="tag">Historic</div>
 <div class="content">a</div>
 <div class="content">b</div>
 <div class="content">c</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working by changing the tag class to read like this.
Note the transform-origin option.

```
transform-origin: left top 0;
position: absolute;
left: -21px;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 9px;
transform: rotate(-90deg);
background: red;
color: white;
bottom: -20px;
text-transform: uppercase;
max-height: 20px;
```